# Redirecting while using PathBase

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have defined `PathBase` like

`new PathString("/test_environment/");`

Then I'm at `https://localhost:5001/test_environment/Login`

and after login it redirects to `/MyController/`

Everything works properly - the controller and its method is reached and serves data properly, but my url in browser is:

`https://localhost:5001/MyController/`

It works fine, but where did `/test_environment/` go?

`MyMethod` in `MyController` has an
`[Route("/")]` attribute

Comment: A little more context (code) would help. Which PatBase do you set, when?

Comment: @bommelding ASP.NET Core MVC -> At startup / Configure with``app.UsePathBase(new PathString("/test_environment/"));``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `app.UsePathBase`, it adds a middleware that extracts the specified path base from request path and postpend it to the request path base.

For `[Route("/")]`, it will generate request `https://localhost:5001/` if you use `RedirectToAction`.

You got `https://localhost:5001/MyController/`, I assume you use `Redirect` to redirect the url.

Try code below in `Login`.

```
public IActionResult Login()
{
    if (Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/test_environment"))
    {
        return Redirect("/");
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect("/test_environment/");
    }
}
```